# keyboard command copy/paste

Tags: 14.04

Its been quite awhile since my last visit here. I have forgotten how to do a simple keyboard copy-paste procedue. I know I highlight the prefered text but forgot what key I hit to paste. This is the best method for pasting terminal commands so you dont mistype a command.
Thank You
Rick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you know when to use SHIFT+INSERT vs CTRL-V vs right-click-paste to paste?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26655/how-do-you-know-when-to-use-shiftinsert-vs-ctrl-v-vs-right-click-paste-to-paste)

Comment: Another related topic : http://askubuntu.com/q/211292/295286

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> = Copy from terminal.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> = Paste to terminal.

Remove <kbd>Shift</kbd> for non-terminal windows.

Answer (score 1):

Pasting highlighted in terminal text can be done via middle mouse click (that's scroll wheel on mouse, right+left click together on touchpad) or via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert(Ins)</kbd> key combination. Aside from that, one can also copy text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Insert(Ins)</kbd>.

Highlighted text+middle click optin works well between terminal-nonterminal windows.