# how to consolidate all clipboards for copy and paste?

Tags: command-line, gui, configuration, clipboard, copy-and-paste

How can I configure copy-paste such that `ctrl-insert` and `ctrl-c` use the same clipboard?

All too often I go to paste and end up pasting a document rather than a link, or other [problematic](https://askubuntu.com/q/26655/847449) paste.

If it's not possible or "easy" to consolidate the clipboards, cannot one or the other simply be disabled?

Comment: You probably mean <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>? Don't worry, these use the same clipboard. You may want to provide some more specific examples of where the copy/paste behaviour does not meet your expectations.

Comment: I'm all too often (well, sometimes) pasting code into IRC rather than a link (to pastebin).

Comment: You should probably add that to your question.